# How to retrieve my facebook wall posts?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

How can I retrieve all my wall feed posts with paging ?
 this code  `$user_profile2 = $facebook->api('/me/feed');` does not retrieve all posts, how can I display posts since specific date ??

Answer (score 0):

use **paging**
see http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

> until, since (a unix timestamp or any date accepted by strtotime): https://graph.facebook.com/search?since=yesterday&q=orange